# Overload resolution failed: - array is not a numerical tuple - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'array'

Tags: python, opencv

Im trying to develope a captcha solver, but I do not know how openCV works properly. Heres is my code, and the message error is below.

````
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

archives = glob.glob('captcha_tratado/*')
for archive in archives:
    image = cv2.imread(archive)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    _, image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    # find contour of each letter
    contours = cv2.findContours(
        image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    letter_regions = []

    for contour in contours:
        (x, y, width, height) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        area = cv2.countourArea(contour)
        if area > 115:
            letter_regions.append((x, y, width, height))
    if len(letter_regions) <= 2:
        pass

    # find contour and separate in individual files
    image_final = cv2.merge([image] * 3)
    i = 0
    for rectangle in letter_regions:
        x, y, width, height = rectangle
        image_letter = image[y-2:y+height+2, x-2:x+width+2]
        i += 1
        fileName = os.path.basename(archive).replace(".png", f"letter{i}.png")
        cv2.imwrite(f'letras/{fileName}', image_letter)
        cv2.rectangle(image_final, (x-2, y-2),
                      (x+width+2, y+height+2), (0, 255, 0), 1)
    fileName = os.path.basename(archive)
    cv2.imwrite(f'identificado/{fileName}', image_final)```




ERROR MESSAGE:
````

```
(x, y, width, height) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
```

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'boundingRect'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - array is not a numerical tuple
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'array'

Comment: what tutorial are you following that suggested to you that `findContours` returns a single thing? questions having this exact same problem show up en masse recently. please answer.

Comment: Does this help? contours = cv2.findContours(
        image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.findCountours` returns two things: The `contour` list retrieved according to the contour approximation method and a list of contour [`hierarchy`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html). Expect two return values even if you don't use one, change the call to the function to this:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

For further reference, [here's](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) the function documentation.